# Does case sensitivity matter when encoding characters in SOAP call?

Tags: xml, soap

I've been running a soap call, and when I encode an ampersand in lower case, i.e `"Jack &amp; Jill"` it works as expected and is received on the other end, but when I send: `"Jack &AMP; Jill"`, I get a 400 bad request error.

I've looked into it, and all I can see is that the tags are case sensitive, but I haven't seen anything that specifically says that encoding is case sensitive.
Is this the case everywhere, or is there something that can be changed to allow uppercase `&AMP;` to be accepted.

Comment: You mean `&AMP;`?

Comment: @LMC yes i do, let me change that sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive. Entity names, like element and attribute names, must use the correct case. The entity name `&amp;` is defined in the XML specification and cannot be written as `&AMP;`.

HTML is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on parser implementation, here are some examples

**Python3 (case sensitive/insensitive)**

```
>>> from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
>>> unescape('&AMP; &amp;')
'&AMP; &'

echo -e '&AMP; \n&amp;' | python3 -c 'import html,sys; print(html.unescape(sys.stdin.read()), end="")'
& 
&
```

**PHP (case sensitive/insensitive)**

```
php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("&AMP; \n&amp;") . "\n";'
&AMP; 
&

php -r 'echo html_entity_decode("&AMP; \n&amp;", $flags = ENT_HTML5) . "\n";'
& 
&
```

**Xmllint (case sensitive)**

```
echo -e '<div>\n&AMP; \n&amp;\n</div>' | xmllint --html --nowrap -
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div>
&amp;AMP; 
&amp;
</div>
</body></html>

echo -e '<div>\n&AMP; \n&amp;\n</div>' | xmllint -
-:2: parser error : Entity 'AMP' not defined
&AMP; 
     ^
```

**recode (case sensitive)**

```
echo -e '&AMP; \n&amp;' | recode html..ascii
&AMP; 
&
```

**Firefox (XML case sensitive/ HTML case insensitive)**

Comment: The question is about XML, but this answer seems to be about HTML.

Comment: The answer provides XML examples too and demonstrates that depends on the parser.

Comment: I think the answer is misleading by suggesting that this depends on the parser implementation. It depends on the language specification, not the parser implementation, and the language specification is different for HTML (versions) and XML.